# C# irreversible string encoding conversion

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8

I use `Newtonsoft.Json` library to parse a simple json file, with content `{"key": "强回声"}` encoded in UTF-8, then I found this confusing thing:

```
byte[] data_utf8 = { 123, 34, 107, 101, 121, 34, 58, 32, 34, 229, 188, 186, 229, 155, 158, 229, 163, 176, 34, 125 };

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", data_utf8));
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data_utf8));

var Ansi_String = Encoding.Default.GetString(data_utf8);
var Ansi_bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Ansi_String);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Ansi_bytes));
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Ansi_bytes));
```

Output:

```
123, 34, 107, 101, 121, 34, 58, 32, 34, 229, 188, 186, 229, 155, 158, 229, 163, 176, 34, 125
{"key": "强回声"}

123, 34, 107, 101, 121, 34, 58, 32, 34, 229, 188, 186, 229, 155, 158, 229, 163, 63, 125
{"key": "强回??}
```

The question is if I have a `string` like `Ansi_String`, is it possible to restore it?

---- **UPDATE** ----
I'm using Chinese locale system, so the above code should replace
`Encoding.Default => Encoding.GetEncoding("gb2312")`

Comment: Looks like it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HhBFNB

Comment: Given that the `Encoding.Default` happens to be an encoding that happens to create a string that happens to represent all the original bytes without converting them to substitution characters, then yes, you can.

Comment: Reminder that the only valid encoding for JSON is UTF-8.

Comment: If the mangled text contains `??`, you can't recover the data. `?` is the error replacement character used when decoding non-Unicode text using the wrong encoding. It's used when a byte or bytes have no corresponding character in the target codepage

Comment: @GSerg Encoding.Default does different things in different environments; IIRC on modern .NET it always returns UTF8, but on older runtimes it returns a machine-configuration-dependent encoding; in reality Encoding.Default should literally never be used, unless you're specifically  trying to answer the question "what is Encoding.Default on this system?", purely for academic interest

Comment: @MarcGravell I probably chose my words poorly. What I meant is "When `Encoding.Default` happens to be an encoding that happens to ... etc". It was meant as the opposite of an encouragement to do so.